# How to query json column using databricks sql?

Tags: sql, databricks

Query is

```
SELECT *
FROM companies c
where c.urls ->> 'Website' = '';
```

Here is the companies table.

| urls |
| --- |
| {'Website': '', 'Twitter': ''} |
| {'Website': 'www.google.com', 'Twitter: ''} |

I'm querying the companies table for rows that have urls column with Website as empty string. However, this query is erroring out in dattabricks sql with:

```
mismatched input '->' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 3, pos 13)
```

Does anyone know how to query the json column in databricks sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following page from the Databricks documentation: [Query semi-structured data in SQL](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/semi-structured.html).

If the content of the column is JSON as a string, then you can make use of this syntax: `<column-name>:<extraction-path>`. For example:

```sql
select * from companies c
where c.urls:Website = ''
```

If the content of the column is a struct, then you can make use of this syntax: `<column-name>:<nested-field>`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM companies c
where c.urls.Website = '';
```